# Not able to execute webdriver scripts on IE

Tags: internet-explorer, webdriver

I want to execute webdriver scripts on IE. I m using the following code for this :-

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "E:\\drivers\\IEDriverServer.exe");  
fDriver= new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

This launches the browser and opens up the desired url, but not able to identify any element on the page. The same code is working fine on FF and chrome. I am using the following code to identify the elements :-

```
login_page_ctrl = findElement(By.id("password"));  
login_page_ctrl.clear();  
login_page_ctrl.sendKeys("1234");
```

Is there any other way of identifying elements on IE in webdriver?

Comment: What error you are getting. provide the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same problem on different occasions, check out this Xpath finder I've found it useful.

https://code.google.com/p/fire-ie-selenium/downloads/detail?name=Fire-IEBrowser1.1.xlsm